# iCloud loses NSData

Tags: ios5, nsdata, exc-bad-access, icloud, nsfilewrapper

I'm creating an app with iCloud. But I have some problems.
It creates directory on iCloud using `NSFileWrapper`, then it creates `NSData` (text) file in `NSFileWrapper` directory.
I'm using this code to convert `NSData` to `NSString`:

```
text=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[fileData bytes]];
```

And it works correctly only on the device, which creates this text file. On other devices file is loaded successfully, but when I try to convert or print it (or other call methods), result is `**BAD_ACCESS**` and object doesn't exist (retain count of file data is 2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be converting it to a string like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[fileData bytes] encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
```

Comment: Yes. I try this way. But filedData was 0x0 0 link when this line executed. But fileData - 17 byte before this line. When I tried read convert copy or call some method for fileData my programm receive signal BAD_ACCESS. But on creator-device all works good.